# Could not find a connected Android device after a while using Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, appium, autotest

When I am using Emulator of Android for Appium automation test, it works at the first time, but after a while(15mins or later), when executing my test again, there's error returns from Appium server:

> ```
> at [object Object].<anonymous> (D:\Program Files\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\android-common.js:344:9)
> at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
> ```
>
> info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Could not find a connected Android device.)","origValue":"Could not find a connected Android device."},"sessionId":null}
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 30552.557 ms - 206

I've restarted by "adb kill-server" and "adb start-server", but no luck. When I am executing "adb devices", the list of devices are empty.

When I re-start my AVD emulator to get a clean env from scratch, it works. But it's very time-cosuming if I restart it everytime.
I am new beginner of Appium. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The simplest solution will be to use Genymotion emulators. They are much more reliable.